# G1on multi effects processor or a normal distortion pedal will have noise?

Tags: effects-pedal, homerecording, noise, buzz, distortion

Whenever I try to record distortion from my G1on Multi effects processor on audacity, I get a high buzz noise...if I try removing the noise from a tool in the software...the recorded guitar doesn't sound well.

Can I get a noiseless distortion if I use a normal distortion/overdrive pedal **(not multi effects)**?

Comment: Changing the pedal will not have much difference I think. Ensure you are not using any additional gain or distortion effect in Audacity. How does it sound when you record as clean guitar?

Comment: @zameb it comes good....no buzz....

Comment: If your guitar is not pre-ampled, then something (Audacity or the input jack) would be adding amplification. If you sum this to the pedal amplification I think you'll get the buzz. Hope someone can tell you a solution. In my case I use an audio interface which helps on problems like this

Comment: An electric guitar will almost always pick up some noise, and a distortion effect will always amplify that noise. However, with equipment that is working properly, you shouldn't have so much noise that the recorded track is unusable. 

You need to track down what the cause of the buzz is. Does the buzz change as you move the guitar around? What about when you touch the strings of the guitar? Do you still get the buzz when the volume of the guitar is turned all the way to zero? How about when the guitar is unplugged?

Answer (score 1):

Buzz implies interference (and it would be easier to figure out what if you could tell us the frequency - although if it is very high pitched I'd assume a faulty or misconfigured digital effect)

Generally speaking, effects pedals should not introduce buzz unless either they are faulty, or in the case of digital effects you can sometimes find settings which will introduce unwanted frequencies. A multi-effects pedal should be no more likely to introduce noise than a single effects pedal.

It is possible that you have this buzz on an undistorted guitar, but the distortion you use is amplifying it, as zameb commented.

One thing that can help is to use a noise gate before your distortion (I think the G1On has one in the Dyn/Fltr section before the OD/Dist section) - this will reduce/remove noise when the guitar is silent.